# how to redirect all pages to another domain, except home page, using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all pages (except for the home page) from one domain to another.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add the example link your home page has?

Comment: The home page would simply be `example.com/`. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rule you have to add to your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
#if not root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
#redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```