# Redirect all pages from one domain to current domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have multiple subdomains, for example:

```
uk.domain.com
us.domain.com
eu.domain.com
```

And I need to redirect all of these subdomains (and any pages that the user tries to access on those subdomains) to:

```
www.domain.com
```

Example:

```
uk.domain.com/page1 -> www.domain.com/page1
uk.domain.com/page2 -> www.domain.com/page2

us.domain.com/page1 -> www.domain.com/page1
us.domain.com/page2 -> www.domain.com/page2

eu.domain.com/page1 -> www.domain.com/page1
eu.domain.com/page2 -> www.domain.com/page2
...etc
```

Is there a rule that can apply to all URLs on each of the subdomains and redirect them to the main domain, with the page in the URL intact, as above?

I have tried example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788341/how-to-redirect-all-pages-to-another-domain-except-home-page-using-htaccess), but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Solved. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788341/how-to-redirect-all-pages-to-another-domain-except-home-page-using-htaccess) works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uk\.something\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somethingelse.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However it needed to be at the top of my .htaccess, since I had other rules that were interfering with it.