# how to redirect all pages except homepage with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

we want to redirect all urls of my website to new address except homepage address

*i also need a code to choose selected user agent

what should i change in this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandexbot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newurl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

i try this but its not working : [how to redirect all pages to another domain, except home page, using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788341/how-to-redirect-all-pages-to-another-domain-except-home-page-using-htaccess)

Comment: And "but its not working" means what _exactly_ ? We cannot somehow magically guess that, you see? And the answer to the question you referenced is correct. So you yourself need to answer the question what is different in your situation. For that it makes sense to 1. name what you exactly mean by "homepage address" and 2. what you actually observe with the attempt you made.

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file and where exactly have you placed this rule in that file (the one from the linked question)? Also make sure you have cleared your browser cache and test with a 302 (temp) redirect to avoid caching issues.

Comment: its wordpress website !
so it has post url like = site.com/postid.php
and category = site.com/category/test

i want to redirect all urls exept homepage (site.com)